# Trying to capture console output of python program in c#

Tags: c#, python, process

I am trying to retrieve console output of a python script by running that script in c# console application. but I don't know what I am doing wrong as I am not able to read any output. Please help me.
This is my code sample:

```
Process proc = new Process();
try
{

    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\python.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"E:/Database/Python Scripts/TestFile.py\" \"E:/Database/Testing.db\"";
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    proc.Start();

    while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("line:" + line);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The End");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error:{0}, Detail: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

finally
{
    //Console.ReadLine();
    proc.Close();
    proc.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false; to true 
then you need to listen for the output event

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\python.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"E:/Database/Python Scripts/TestFile.py\" \"E:/Database/Testing.db\"";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
proc.OutputDataReceived+= ProcessOutputHandler;
proc.Start();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine(); 

  private void ProcessOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        //get the data using e.Data

    }
```

You can do the same thing for the ErrorOutput Since they are seperate streams you can get. To listen for error just add an event listener for `proc.ErrorDataReceived+= ProcessErrorOutputHandler;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried after making the change you suggested but it still does not print what's inside the while loop. so I tried debugging my program and i realized that it's not going into while loop however targeted python script runs. because i saw a python thread running in my task manager and when i end that task from task manager , then my program printed "The End" which is just after the while loop. Do you have any idea why it is acting like that..??

Comment: did you try with the ErrorDataReceived event?

Comment: I updated the answer  you also need to add these lines proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

Comment: Yes, I just tried with OutputDataReceived event too. my program still acting the same i.e. console windows gets nothing printed till i close that task from task manager,and then it prints "The End".
here's my updated code:

Comment: please see the updated answer you need to add two more lines

Comment: proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                
                proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                proc.OutputDataReceived += OutputHandler;
                proc.ErrorDataReceived += OutputHandler;

                proc.Start();

                
                proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
                proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
                proc.WaitForExit();
                Console.WriteLine("The End");
                Console.ReadLine();

Comment: put a Console.WriteLine(e.Data); on the OutputHandler

Comment: yes i did..my output handler code is:
static void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
        {
            if(outLine.Data != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Output:" + outLine.Data);
            }
            
        }

Comment: i am using the code mentioned in the answer and it hitting the outputhandler i am not sure what is going on there, sorry there is not much i can do more

Comment: python don't use "normal" stdout. you get your output after the scrip has finished